# Api controller does not work because of unsupported media type

Tags: .net

.Net API controller json content-type or parameter type mismatch problem.

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
> "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
> "status": 415,
> "traceId": "00-7afc8f3ea707214b897d04a298f7b3a6-fc9689395692c54f-00"
> }

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        using (var Context = new TContext()) // getting appropriate context generic
        {
        var result = Context.Orders.Add(entity); // I've assumed that DBSet for your order table is Orders
        Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I need to see the API body, and please put the exception details here

Comment: Question Edited.

Comment: Dear I don't know what you are trying to do with your code, so it throws an exception like you mentioned, 
however I'll try to rewrite your code in the way that i find it helpful
           `order.OrderItems = null;
            order.OrderItems[0].Order = order; // I don't know what you tried to do here, but it will throw an reference not set to an instance exception

            _context.orders.Add(order);
            _context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I think the problem is with your post request body, it must be like this:

`{
  "orderItems": [
    {
      "amount": 10,
      "product": {
        "name": "Test new product"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233179/discussion-between-mohammed-alzamil-and-nostuff).